# Fine tuning a deep learning model using my own dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I have the code to classify the images as Nude or Non nude. It is implemented on deep learning with tensor flow python. The code can be founded in [Tensorflow Implementation of Yahoo's Open NSFW Model](https://github.com/mdietrichstein/tensorflow-open_nsfw)

I want to add some more images in to the dataset on order to do fine tuning. How can I do fine tuning in this implementation by using another dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Just load their [model](https://github.com/mdietrichstein/tensorflow-open_nsfw/blob/master/model.py) and initialize its weights with the [ones they provide](https://github.com/mdietrichstein/tensorflow-open_nsfw/tree/master/data), similar to how they do it [here](https://github.com/mdietrichstein/tensorflow-open_nsfw/blob/master/classify_nsfw.py#L43). Assuming that you are familiar with tensorflow, you should then proceed to train that model on your images.

Besides [this blog post](https://yahooeng.tumblr.com/post/151148689421/open-sourcing-a-deep-learning-solution-for) I'm not aware of any other publications the team has made on their work. This is a bit of an issue as they don't state their training parameters (choice of optimizer, learning rate, etc.). If you want to fine-tune this model you will have to experiment a bit in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Do they give you the original dataset that the provided model is trained off of? If so, you can easily just add your own dataset to their dataset, and train a completely new model based on the combined dataset.

I wrote more about this "combined" dataset, where you can add more or less data, [here](https://www.energize.ai/stockprediction/).

Good Luck!